# Rank of an $m$ by $n$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, number-theory

Can anyone state, in plain English, how to find the rank of an $m$ by $n$ matrix?

1. Is it necessary to perform Gaussian elimination first, or translate it into upper triangle form (or however it is called)?

Note that $m$ and $n$ may not be the same, so I am not purely referring to square matrices.

2. What does the rank tell us about the matrix?
3. Does any of these things change when we're talking about modular equations instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauß's row reduction is a technique to compute the rank of a matrix.

There are two definitions of the rank of a matrix:

- the row rank is the number of linearly independent rows of the matrix. It is this rank that row-reduction algorithm computes.
- the column rank is the number of linearly independent columns of the matrix. We might compute it with column operations. It has a natural interpretation: it is the dimension of the image of the associated linear map.

It  happens one shows these two ranks are equal. This answers question 2.

For the last question it is almost the same for modular equations. Ineed it is exactly the same for a prime modulus $p$, because we then work on the *field* $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$. If the modulus is not prime, things are more complex, because we the work with modules on a commutative ring, which has zero-divisors, modules do not necessarily have a basis (if they have, they're called *free modules*).

Furthermore a free submodule and a free module may have the same rank without being equal. The simplest example is the ring $\mathbf Z$, which is free of rank $1$  as a $\mathbf Z$-module. Its submodules  are simply its ideals, and as $\mathbf Z$ is a P.I.D., all its submodules are free of rank $1$).

Answer (score 0):

1) Gaussian elimination is not necessary. A QR decomposition will also give you the rank of a matrix. That means that some sequence of rotations and reflections of the column vectors of your matrix will produce a set of vectors that will have zeros for components above the rank.

2) The rank is the number of dimensions that are not flattened by the associated transformation. The range of the transformation is a vector space that has the same dimension as the rank.

3) Gaussian elimination is possible on matrices over any field. The rank is well defined for linear transformations between any vector spaces. That is the case for finite fields. If the ring is not a field, then it might not be possible to perform Gaussian elimination.